# Custom widget properties in GTK3

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk3

I have a widget like so:

```
class MyWidget(Gtk.Grid):
    pass
```

I need to add a custom property to it so that it can be accessed as so:

```
my_widget = MyWidget()    
my_widget.props.my_custom_property = 12
```

I could use a property decorator in `MyWidget` and access it like `my_widget.my_custom_property = 12` but I'd like for the widget's interface to be consistent with the other library widgets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gtk widgets are based on [GObject](http://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). There are examples for [subclassing](http://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/api/gobject.html#examples) and [creating properties](http://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/api/properties.html#properties), which are easy to put together:

```
class MyWidget(Gtk.Grid):
    @GObject.Property
    def my_custom_property(self):
        return self._my_custom_property

    @my_custom_property.setter
    def my_custom_property(self, value):
        self._my_custom_property = value
```

---

Your class can now be used like any other GObject:

```
my_widget = MyWidget()    
my_widget.props.my_custom_property = 12
my_widget.get_property('my-custom-property'))  # 12
```

Comment: Just a few questions, is there a way to access the property's default value as defined in the `__gproperties__` dict? Is `GObject.type_register(MyWidget)` necessary since it still works without it? And, what would you use for the min/max values if your property doesn't require bounds?

Comment: @eugenhu Answer overhauled.

Comment: Oh wow that's a lot nicer, I was searching on google for something like this, cheers.

Comment: Is there a way to access the custom property in glade?