# Exposing GTK3 custom widget properties in glade

Tags: gtk3, glade, custom-widgets

I can add a custom widget to GTK, as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1471492/78169). Now I'd like to add properties to the custom widget and have them show up in glade. Is this possible?

I have added properties to the custom widget as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48382610/custom-widget-properties-in-gtk3) but the properties do not show up in glade.

---

**Update**

It appears that the glade catalogue supports a `<parameter-spec>` element that can be used to define properties to be exposed within glade as shown below.

```
<glade-widget-class title="Awesome TextView" name="AwesomeTextView" generic-name="awesome_text_view">
    <properties>
        <property id="num_fidgets" name="Number of fidgets" default="4" save="False" custom-layout="True">
        <parameter-spec>
            <type>GParamInt</type>
            <min>4</min>
        </parameter-spec>
        <tooltip>The number of fidgets</tooltip>
        </property>
    </properties>
</glade-widget-class>
```

I have defined one such property but it does not show in glade. Rather I get the error message:

```
GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:07:45.433: g_object_set_is_valid_property: object class 'AwesomeTextView' has no property named 'num-fidgets'
```

Where the custom widget `AwesomeTextView` is essentially defined as:

```
class AwesomeTextView (Gtk.TextView):
    __gtype_name__ = 'AwesomeTextView'
    
    num_fidgets = GObject.Property(type=int, default='4', nick='num_Fidgets')
```

<s>*The `<parameter-spec>`s appear to be undocumented. Thankfully though there are examples of the the supported `<type>`s in the glade [repo](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glade/-/blob/master/plugins/gtk%2B/gtk%2B.xml).*</s>

**Correction**: `<parameter-spec>`s are [documented](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gladeui/3.36/catalog.html). This documentation can be supplemented with examples of the supported `<type>`s in the glade [repo](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glade/-/blob/master/plugins/gtk%2B/gtk%2B.xml).

---

**Update2**

Found the cause of the error. The default argument has the wrong type -- `str` instead of `int`. The property should be:

```
num_fidgets = GObject.Property(type=int, default=4, nick='num_Fidgets')
```

Glade no longer emits an error. But the property does not show up in the UI.

Comment: Could you be a little more clear on what you mean by "show up in Glade?" Are you using a Glade file, and you want these properties to be written to the Glade file? Or are you saying that you can't find these properties in the Glade application?

Comment: @SylvesterKruin I would like to expose my widget properties in glade. For example my widget has a `num_fidgets` property. I would like this property to be settable in glade. I'm adding more information to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Overly complicated solution** (See update for simpler solution)

Found the final piece. Do not set the `<property>` attribute `custom-layout` to `"True"` -- unless you know what are doing i.e. you know how to layout the property, properly (I don't, at least not yet). My advise, set `custom-layout="False"` in the updated catalogue shown below:

```
<glade-catalog name="awesome_text_view" library="gladepython" domain="glade-3" depends="gtk+">
    <init-function>glade_python_init</init-function>

    <glade-widget-classes>
        <glade-widget-class title="Awesome TextView" name="AwesomeTextView" generic-name="awesome_text_view">
            <properties>
                <property id="num_fidgets" name="Number of fidgets" default="4" save="True" custom-layout="False">
                    <parameter-spec>
                        <type>GParamInt</type>
                        <min>4</min>
                    </parameter-spec>
                    <tooltip>The number of fidgets</tooltip>
                </property>
            </properties>
        </glade-widget-class>
    </glade-widget-classes>

    <glade-widget-group name="Python" title="Python">
        <glade-widget-class-ref name="AwesomeTextView"/>
    </glade-widget-group>
</glade-catalog>
```

Result:

[image: custom widget property in glage]

For completeness here is the sample custom widget class

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import GObject
from gi.repository import Gtk

class AwesomeTextView(Gtk.TextView):
    __gtype_name__ = 'AwesomeTextView'
    num_fidgets = GObject.Property(type=int, default=4, nick='num_fidgets')

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.TextView.__init__(self)
```

---

**Update**

Turns out the `nick` argument in the property declaration

```
num_fidgets = GObject.Property(type=int, default=4, nick='num_fidgets')
```

is all that's required to for the property to show up in the glade UI. The element `<properties>` would be more appropriate for more complicated values e.g. enums. I'm leaving the more complicated answer in place in the event that its of use to anyone.